# set the environment variable using python

Tags: python, linux, shell

I basically want to set path for some of the variables using source  .
Scripting language python .subprocess.call call source /home/local/APPSCRIPT.env but not actually setting the environment variable.

sample script :

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess

subcall=subprocess.call(['source /home/local/APPSCRIPT.env'],shell=True)
```

Please suggest how can i set the environment variable  from APPSCRIPT.env

APPSCRIPT.env :

```
export xxx_SIZE=1
export yyy_USE=FALSE
export zzz_INCREMENTAL=FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.

`subprocess` runs in, well, a subprocess. There's no way for any environment changes made in a subprocess to affect the calling process.

The only way to change environment variables for the current process in Python is to directly modify the `sys.environ` dictionary.

Comment: Are the changes made in the `sys.environ` dict accessible from outside Python? say from the cmd for example?

Comment: No, for precisely the same reason.

Comment: I have to set multiple environment variable in one shot . Could you please give some example or any doc link so i can refer